# Force Linux to use only memory over 4G?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux device driver that interfaces to a device that, in theory, can perform DMA using 64-bit addresses.  I'd like to test to see that this actually works.

Is there a simple way that I can force a Linux machine not to use any memory below physical address 4G?  It's OK if the kernel image is in low memory; I just want to be able to force a situation where I know all my dynamically allocated buffers, and any kernel or user buffers allocated for me are not addressable in 32 bits.  This is a little brute force, but would be more comprehensive than anything else I can think of.

This should help me catch (1) hardware that wasn't configured correctly or loaded with the full address (or is just plain broken) as well as (2) accidental and unnecessary use of bounce buffers (because there's nowhere to bounce to).

**clarification**: I'm running x86_64, so I don't care about most of the old 32-bit addressing issues.  I just want to test that a driver can correctly interface with multitudes of buffers using 64-bit physical addresses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[/usr/src/linux/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

```
        memmap=exactmap [KNL,X86] Enable setting of an exact
                        E820 memory map, as specified by the user.
                        Such memmap=exactmap lines can be constructed based on
                        BIOS output or other requirements. See the memmap=nn@ss
                        option description.

        memmap=nn[KMG]@ss[KMG]
                        [KNL] Force usage of a specific region of memory
                        Region of memory to be used, from ss to ss+nn.

        memmap=nn[KMG]#ss[KMG]
                        [KNL,ACPI] Mark specific memory as ACPI data.
                        Region of memory to be used, from ss to ss+nn.

        memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]
                        [KNL,ACPI] Mark specific memory as reserved.
                        Region of memory to be used, from ss to ss+nn.
                        Example: Exclude memory from 0x18690000-0x1869ffff
                                 memmap=64K$0x18690000
                                 or
                                 memmap=0x10000$0x18690000
```

If you add `memmap=4G$0` to the kernel's boot parameters, the lower 4GB of physical memory will no longer be accessible.  Also, your system will no longer boot... but some variation hereof (`memmap=3584M$512M`?) may allow for enough memory below 4GB for the system to boot but not enough that your driver's DMA buffers will be allocated there.

Comment: That seems to be pretty close to what I need.  There are two caveats: first, memmap=nn$ss can prevent the kernel from reading memory-mapped devices, including everything on the PCI/PCIe bus.  So that needs to be worked around.

Second, I have no way of preventing memory needed at boot but then freed (such as the initrd image) from being recycled as DMA buffers.

Still a useful answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there's an option within kernel configuration to use PAE extensions which will enable you to use more than 4GB (I am a bit rusty on the kernel config - last kernel I recompiled was 2.6.4 - so please excuse my lack of recall). You do know how to trigger a kernel config

`make clean && make menuconfig`

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: You misunderstand; I want to boot a system that _only_ uses >4GB memory.

Comment: @Eric Seppanen: My apologies! Yup! I definitely misunderstood. When I saw ephemient's answer I went duh! I completely forgot about all that memmap boot parameter but never used it...it makes you realize when you have not-a-lot-of memory you don't bother to use those boot parameters... sorry for the confusion! :(