# Reserve memory chunks out of multiple NUMA nodes

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, numa

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1911473/143897) question discusses how to force the linux kernel to exclude some memory from being used(and thus visible to the kernel). with `memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]` you can exclude 1 chunk of memory.

Is it possible to provide this kernel boot parameter multiple times to exclude multiple sections of the physical memory from various NUMA Nodes.

Have you tried it out ? any suggestions ?

Comment: As I see in sources, `memmap` has no loop in parsing code: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6/arch/x86/kernel/e820.c#L838 so only one chunk is possible for single memmap. But what you can try to do: pass the memmap parameter several times.

Comment: And yes, multiple `memmap`s should work because: there is a loop in global param parsing code: [kernel/params.c:180](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6/kernel/params.c#L180). And code in e820.c/.h saves region into [in array](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6/arch/x86/kernel/e820.c#L110) of size ... [128 + 3*MAX_NUMNODES](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6/arch/x86/include/asm/e820.h#L32)