# mapping memory reserved by mmap kernel boot param into user space

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1911473/143897) question, i am reserving a memory chunk at the boot time using a kernel boot parameter `memmap=8G$64G`

I have written a [character driver](http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/08/writing-linux-device-driver-for-kernels.html) kernel module which , <strike>during initialization does a ioremap of this reserved memory chunk.</strike>
As explained [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/mmap-of-several-gb-of-reserved-memory-using-805818/#post3972954) , in my driver `mmap` all i need to do is `remap_pfn_range` for this memory chunk pointer returned by the `ioremap`.

I am running this on **3.0 linux kernel**. My user space application opens this memory chunk as a device mounted by the driver. When i do  `mmap` from the use space application i see a **system hang.** my `dmesg` don't provide me much information.

**Any inputs ?**

```cpp
static int __init myDev_module_init(void)
{
   int retval;

   myDev_major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &myDevfops);
   if (myDev_major < 0) 
   {
       err("failed to register device: error %d\n", myDev_major);
       retval = myDev_major;
       goto FAILED_CHRDEVREG;
   }

   myDev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(myDev_class)) 
   {   
       err("failed to register device class '%s'\n", CLASS_NAME);
       retval = PTR_ERR(myDev_class);
       goto FAILED_CLASSREG;
   }


   myDev_device = device_create(myDev_class, NULL, MKDEV(myDev_major, 0), NULL, CLASS_NAME "_" DEVICE_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(myDev_device)) 
   {
       err("failed to create device '%s_%s'\n", CLASS_NAME, DEVICE_NAME);
       retval = PTR_ERR(myDev_device);
       goto FAILED_DEVREG;
   }
```

here the `myDev.startOffset` is initialized to `#define`d  64GB and `myDev.memSize` to 8GB.

```cpp
 //myDev.startAddr = ioremap(myDev.startOffset,myDev.memSize);

 //memset_io(myDev.startAddr, 0, myDev.memSize);  
 return 0;

  FAILED_DEVREG:
   class_unregister(myDev_class);
   class_destroy(myDev_class);
  FAILED_CLASSREG:
   unregister_chrdev(myDev_major, DEVICE_NAME);
  FAILED_CHRDEVREG:
   return -1;
}

static int myDev_device_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* filp)
{
    dbg("");

    if ( ((filp->f_flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_WRONLY) || ((filp->f_flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_RDWR) ) 
    {
        warn(" Opening the device with write access\n");
        //return -EACCES;
    }

    info(" device Open is called\n");
    filp->private_data = &myDev;
    return 0;
 }
```

And the `mmap` is pretty straight forward.

```cpp
static int myDev_device_mmap(struct file * f, struct vm_area_struct * vma)
{
 int retval = 0;
struct myDevDev * pDev = (struct myDevDev *)(f->private_data);

dbg("");
if(vma)
{
    if(f)
    {
        if(f->private_data)
            warn("mmap: f->private_data  : %p\n", f->private_data);
        else
            warn(" mmap :f->private_data  : NULL \n");
    }
    else
    {
        warn("mmap: f  :NULL\n");
    }
    warn(": mmap: vm start : %lu\n", vma->vm_start);
    warn(" mmap: vm end  : %lu\n", vma->vm_end);
    warn(" mmap: vm pg offset  : %lu\n", vma->vm_pgoff);


    
    //retval = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pDev->startOffset >> PAGE_SHIFT,    pDev->memSize, PAGE_SHARED) ;
    // retval = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pDev->startAddr >> PAGE_SHIFT,    pDev->memSize, PAGE_SHARED) ;
    //retval = remap_pfn_range(vma,pDev->startAddr ,pDev->startOffset >> PAGE_SHIFT,  pDev->memSize, PAGE_SHARED);
    retval = remap_pfn_range(vma,vma->vm_start ,pDev->startOffset >> PAGE_SHIFT,  pDev->memSize, PAGE_SHARED);
    if(retval <0)
    {
        warn(" ERROR : in mapping kernel virtual space to user space return value : %d \n",retval);
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    
    //if(0)
    {
        vma->vm_flags |=VM_LOCKED;
        vma->vm_ops = &myRemapVMOps;
        vma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;

        vma->vm_private_data = f->private_data;
        myDevice_VMA_Open(vma);
    }
}
else
{
    warn ("vma is NULL");
}

dbg(" Done ");
warn("mmpaing done : \n");

return 0;
}
```

from my user space application i am doing the following :

```cpp
int err, i=0;
void * mptr = NULL;
printf(" Access the reserved memory chunk \n  ");
int fd = open("/dev/myDevice", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

if(fd <=0)
{
    printf("ERROR: my device driver is not loaded \n");
    return 1;
}

  printf("\n mmaping mem chunk size :%llu pagesize :%lu input mptr :%p\n", sz,getpagesize (), mptr);

  mptr = mmap(0, sz , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, fd, 0);

if(mptr == MAP_FAILED) 
{
    close(fd);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    printf("\nmmapped mem address %p\n",mptr);
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nmmapped mem address %p\n",mptr);

//char * ptr = (char *)mptr;
//*ptr = 'a';

//int * pInt =  (int *) (((char *) mptr)+1); 
//for(;i<10000; ++i)
{
  //  pInt[i] = 2*i;
}

 /* free the mmapped memory
 */
if (munmap(mptr, sz) == -1) 
{
    perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
}

close(fd);
```

Observation :

I don't see the size getting reflected in the `(vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start)` which for some reason is **ALWAYS 4K.**

Comment: Usually *request_mem_region()* is called to declare/reserve the chunk of phys address space before calling *ioremap()*.  What does `/proc/iomem` show?  If the "system hangs" (as opposed to just the user app) then the problem would be something in the kernel!

Comment: `/proc/iomem` shows that chunk to be reserved `1000000000-1280000000 : reserved`

Comment: `numactl --hardware` already shows me that the memory chunk is not reflected in the numa nodes thus it won't be visible to the kernel space.

Comment: not sure if we still need to do `request_mem_region()` ?

Comment: `/proc/vmallocinfo` shows the `ioremapped` memory chunk though !i printed the address returned by the `ioremap` in the device driver `init` and it matches the `vmallocinfo` entry !

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use standard phram driver in steps to access your memory from userspace. No coding is needed. Kernel recompilation at maximum.
2. Do You really have more then 64Gb of RAM? Does Your hardware really support it?

Comment: we support more than 128GB of RAM

Comment: Hm. It's interested. Which architecture do you use? AFAIK Linux usually do not expect more then 64GB Memory.

Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> When i do mmap from the use space application i see a system hang.

Before you can use the remap_pfn_range() API, see documentation inlined inside mm/memory.c (of kernel source), and it indicated that you have to have held the mm semaphore first.

```
/**
 * remap_pfn_range - remap kernel memory to userspace
 * @vma: user vma to map to
 * @addr: target user address to start at
 * @pfn: physical address of kernel memory
 * @size: size of map area
 * @prot: page protection flags for this mapping
 *
 *  Note: this is only safe if the mm semaphore is held when called.
 */
```

And how to acquire the semaphore is via up_read() and down_read() API - just "grep" for up_read inside the mm directory and there are many examples:

```
mempolicy.c:    up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
migrate.c:  up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
mincore.c:      up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
mmap.c:     up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
msync.c:            up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
nommu.c:    up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
```

Comment: If you write to that area you probably will need to call up_write/down_write instead.